# Pushing only one file to GIT

Tags: git

Before I do mistake, I need to know what I'm about to do is correct. I did some researches but still want make sure because I'm new to GIT and scared of messing whole project. Yes there are a lot of examples but I'm confused. That's all.

I have 3 files in local GIT and just want to commit one of them and push it to live GIT. So are these steps correct?

**WHAT I THINK I SHOULD DO !!!**

```
sudo git add web/js/admin/design.js
sudo git commit -m 'Bug fix'
sudo git push origin sprint-6
```

**GIT STATUS:**

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/Hello/AdminBundle/Controller/DesignController.php
    modified:   web/js/admin/design.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    src/Hello/AdminBundle/Utility/DesignPublisher.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Given your `git status` seems that you're doing the correct steps.

Comment: Why do you call Git with sudo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You commit only files that are added to the repository. So if you need only one file then add only the one file.

```
git add src/Hello/AdminBundle/Controller/DesignController.php
```

And then commit it. Files that are untracked are not included in the repo. There you have to add it first.

Comment: I want to push only 'web/js/admin/design.js' so what I've written above is correct. Am I right?

Answer (score 7):

If we want to commit and push only a single file out of all modified/new files, we need to commit that particular file first. Here are the steps to commit and push a single file:

1. Commit single file:

   ```
   git commit -m 'your comment' path/to/your/file.txt
   ```
2. Push file to git:

   ```
   git push remote-name current-branch-name
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me but if you want to be sure you can run `git push` with the `--dry-run` option (`-n` for short).

If you make a mistake you can revert the commit and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single git command to push a single file to a remote repo as of the time of this reply rather you just have to commit the file you want to push to github alone with `git add <filename>` followed by `git commit -m "<commit msg>" <filename>` then `git push <remote> <branch>`

Comment: This just repeats existing answers. Please don't add duplicate answers.